# My video youtube is blurred

Tags: video, iframe, youtube

I am using iframe to insert a youtube video.
The video is the result of key word, so that the optimal size of the video varies from one video to another, which make the displayed video is blurred.

```
<iframe width="320" height="180" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&amp;list=fashion mode&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Would you have a solution?
Thank you very much!
And happy new year!

Comment: you meant width and height varies and what is your current issue.